# Python importing multiple scripts

Tags: python, debugging, module

I've been working on a python script that will require multiple libraries to be imported.

At the moment my directory structure is

```
program/
    main.py
    libs/
        __init__.py
        dbconnect.py
        library01.py
        library02.py
        library03.py
```

My dbconnect.py which has the following contents

```
import psycopg2

class dbconnect:

    def __init__(self):
        self.var_parameters = "host='localhost' dbname='devdb' user='temp' password='temp'"

    def pgsql(self):
        try:
            var_pgsqlConn = psycopg2.connect(self.var_parameters)
        except:
            print("connection failed")

    return var_pgsqlConn
```

I am able to import and use this in my main.py using

```
from libs.dbconnect import dbconnect

class_dbconnect = dbconnect()
var_pgsqlConn = class_dbconnect.pgsql()
```

This works as expected however I am trying to import all of the library scripts each which have similar contents to bellow

```
def library01():
    print("empty for now but this is library 01")
```

I have added to my __init__.py script

```
__all__ = ["library01", "library02"]
```

Then in my main.py I tried to import and use them as bellow

```
from libs import *

library01()
```

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose content in your library0x.py are different (the functions/class have different names)

The best way is to import all your subfiles content in the `__init__.py`

```
# __init__.py
from .dbconnect import *
from .library01 import *
from .library02 import *
from .library03 import *
```

Then you can use the following :

```
from libs import library01, library02
```

If you want to restrict for some reasons importation with the wildcard (`*`) in your library0x.py files, you can define a `__all__` variable containing all the names of the function you will import with the wildcard :

```
# library01.py

__all__ = ["library01"]

def a_local_function():
    print "Local !"

def library01():
    print "My library function"
```

Then, by doing `from .library01 import *`, only the function `library01` will be import.

---

EDIT: Maybe i missunderstand the question : here are some ways to import the function `library01` in the file `library01.py` :

```
# Example 1:
from libs.library01 import library01
library01()

# Example 2:
import libs.library01
libs.library01.library01()

# Example 3:
import libs.library01 as library01
library01.library01()
```

Comment: This is a very thorough answer which is great. Your first answer is the one I was looking for the bulk import of small library functions

Answer (score 1):

In your case `library01` is a *module* which contains a *function* named `library01`. You import the `library01` module and try to call it as a function. That's the problem. You should call the function like this:

```
library01.library01()
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution but it looks kind of messy to use the name of the file as well as the name of the function considering there will possibly be hundreds of them but this will definitely be useful for importing bigger scripts. Thanks a bunch